# estimation of the ground plane in pinhole camera model

Tags: computer-vision, geometry, projection, camera-calibration, perspectivecamera

I am trying to understand the pinhole camera model and the geometry behind some computer vision and camera calibration stuff that I am looking at.

So, if I  understand correctly, the pinhole camera model maps the pixel coordinates to 3D real world coordinates. So, the model looks as:

```
y = K [R|T]x
```

Here `y` is pixel coordinates in homogeneous coordinates, `R|T` represent the extrinsic transformation matrix and `x` is the 3D world coordinates also in homogeneous coordinates.

Now, I am looking at a presentation which says

> project the center of the focus region onto the ground plane using [R|T]

Now the center of the focus region is just taken to be the center of the image. I am not sure how I can estimate the ground plane? Assuming, the point to be projected is in input space, the projection should that be computed by inverting the [R|T] matrix and multiplying that point by the inverted matrix?

**EDIT**
Source here on page 29: http://romilbhardwaj.github.io/static/BuildSys_v1.pdf

Comment: Signal Processing might be the place for computer vision questions  of general and mathematical nature, https://dsp.stackexchange.com/    S.O. is fine if it's coding details, API technicalities, compiling, etc.

Comment: @Luca Can you share the source of this statement? Some context might help here.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Yes, I have added a link to the presentation which I was using. It is basically, after I get the calibration matrix, to project some fixed point onto the ground plane.

Comment: That approach assumes that you know where the ground plane is or at least that it can be inferred from the image. Nothing that a bare pinhole camera model gives you.